# Edit Exploit in Metasploit

Tags: metasploit

How can I change Metasploit module source, I want to change some URL in an exploit.

I have tried the `edit` command and successfully edited this line to what I want, but changes are not reflected, the exploit has the same behavior as before, it looks like I haven't changed anything, but when I to try edit it again, I see my changes!

Does Metasploit save this anywhere else?

Comment: Metasploit is written within Ruby not hacklang. So you need to edit the exploit file and reopen your metasploit terminal. Look [here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Why-Ruby%3F) for more informations.

Comment: i have tried this but when i execute the exploit nothing changed @ChihebNexus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do u want to edit the Metasploit framework or just one of the exploits?
If u just want to edit an exploit,find the location, edit it ,and reload all the modules by the command "reload_all".

Answer (score 2):

Just reload your module with `reload` right after you finished with `edit`